# Existence and uniqueness of heat equation on domain with discontinuous boundary

Tags: reference-request, parabolic-pde

as the title says i'm looking for references dealing with heat equation with discontinuous boundary conditions. More precisely, let $\lambda_{L},\lambda_{U}$  functions defined on the interval $[0,T]$ such that $\lambda_{L}(t)<\lambda_{U}(t)$ for each $t\in [0,T]$. Moreover let  $$D:= \lbrace t_{1},\ldots,t_{N}\rbrace \subset (0,T)$$
and suppose the functions $\lambda_{L},\lambda_{U}$  are smooth on  $[0,T]\setminus D$ and on $D$ they have simple jumps (like Heaviside function).
Now suppose I want to solve for $t\in [0,T]$ the following problem
$$\begin{cases} \partial_{t}u-\partial_{x}^{2}u=0 &\\
u(x,0)=f(x)& x\in [\lambda_{L}(0),\lambda_{U}(0)]  \\
u(\lambda_{L}(t),t)=0 &t\in [0,T]\\
u(\lambda_{U}(t),t)=0 &t\in [0,T] 
\end{cases}$$
with $f(x)$ smooth and compatible with the other boundary conditions. I would like to know if the problem is solvable, if the solution is unique and the kind of regularity of solution. I'm thinking about solving the heat equation with the same boundary conditions but with mollified $\lambda_{L},\lambda_{U}$ and  then considering the limit of the solutions as the mollification parameter goes to zero. But this is only a superficial thought and the limit probably does not exist. So i would like to know if there is literature i can study on this kind of problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Suppose at the initial moment the domain was $[-1,1]$ and at the moment $t_1$ become $[-2,2]$. To be uniquely solvable problem should have initial data assigned on $[-2,2]$ and from the solution on $[0,t_1]$ it will be determined on $[-1,1]$ only.

Comment: But if to assign arbitrary values on $[-2,2]\backslash[-1,1]$ at $t=t_1$ then one can solve the problem on $[t_1,t_2]$ etc. So your mollifying will not always work. When the domain is "expanded" at $t=t_i$ one can put any "intermediary" initial conditions, but if the domain is "contracted"  the solution on mollified boundary has to coincide in the limit with the limit values $u(x,t)$ as $t\to t_1-0$.

Comment: So it is like this: make the side boundary continuous by adding horizontal segments. Then for unique solvability one can set any conditions on some segments and on others the values are predetermined by the solution at the earlier time moments.